# is there a function to test an object instance that has a callback in js?

Tags: javascript, object, promise, callback, sinon

Im using sinon to stub an instance of an object that has inside a function with a callback, how can i test it?.
i dont know how to test this, that throws me an error.

this is using js with sinon and mocha.

the function is:

```
import tracker from 'pivotaltracker';

export async function getPivotalProjects(token) {
  const clientTracker = new tracker.Client(token);
  const userProjects = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    clientTracker.projects.all((error, projects) => (projects ? resolve(projects) : reject(error)));
  });
  return userProjects();
```

and the test is:

```
import tracker from 'pivotaltracker';
let spyTracker;
    beforeEach(() => {
      spyTracker = sinon.stub(tracker, 'Client');
    });

it('should do the request to get the activities from projects.', async () => {
      spyTracker.callsArgWith(1, null, [true, 'token']);
      // spyTracker.projects.all.returns('token');
      await PivotalTrackerApi.getPivotalProjects('token');
      sinon.assert.threw(spyTracker);
spyTracker.restore();
    });
```

what is wrong on that? if anyone could helpme will be great.

Comment: `that throws me an error` **an** error you say, how interesting, is it any error in particular? :p

Comment: oh sorry, it is an miss understanding,  i tried to say, that actuallty throws me an error for the implementation of the test, i dont know how to test it

Comment: OK, let me post this in as plain English as I can ... Please include the error you are getting in the question as "an error" is not enough information and you may as well have not mentioned it if you're not going to reveal what the error is

Comment: sorry again, the error is this one:      `Error: the function [Function] was thrown, throw an Error :).`;  sorry, im learning, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getPivotalProjects` can be simplified to this:

```
export async function getPivotalProjects(token) {
  const clientTracker = new tracker.Client(token);
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    clientTracker.projects.all((error, projects) => (projects ? resolve(projects) : reject(error)));
  });
}
```

...and it can be tested like this:

```
let clientStub;

beforeEach(() => {
  clientStub = sinon.stub(tracker, 'Client');
});

it('should do the request to get the activities from projects.', async () => {
  const allSpy = sinon.spy();
  clientStub.callsFake((token) => ({ projects: { all: allSpy } }));
  const promise = PivotalTrackerApi.getPivotalProjects('token');
  sinon.assert.calledWith(clientStub, 'token');  // Success!
  sinon.assert.called(allSpy);  // Success!
  const callback = allSpy.lastCall.args[0];
  callback(null, 'my projects');
  const result = await promise;
  expect(result).to.equal('my projects');  // Success!
});
```